# Elasticsearch associating exact match terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search index of filenames containing over 100,000 entries that share about 500 unique variations of the main `filename` field. I have recently made some modifications to certain filename values that are being generated from my data. I was wondering if there is a way to link certain queries to return an exact match. In the following query:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "filename": "foo-bar"
        }
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

how would it be possible to modify the index and associate the results so that above query will also match results `foo-bar-baz`, but not `foo-bar-foo` or any other variation?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: didi you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: I think what I am going to have to do in this case is create a separate keywords index or field for each of these entries that contains the common query terms they are sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a term query instead of a match query. Perfect to use on a keyword:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data and search query. (Using the default mapping)

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "fileName": "foo-bar"
}
{
    "fileName": "foo-bar-baz"
}
{
    "fileName": "foo-bar-foo"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fileName.keyword": "foo-bar" 
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fileName.keyword": "foo-bar-baz" 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.9808291,
                "_source": {
                    "fileName": "foo-bar"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.9808291,
                "_source": {
                    "fileName": "foo-bar-baz"
                }
            }
        ]
```